# Connect to Postgres DB by a user which has no password

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I created a user by:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER sample;"
```

Then created a database:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE practice OWNER sample;"
```

Now I'm trying to connect to this DB by following snippet:

```
dsn := url.URL{
        User:     url.UserPassword("sample", ""),
        Scheme:   "postgres",
        Host:     fmt.Sprintf("%s", "localhost"),
        Path:     "practice",
        RawQuery: (&url.Values{"sslmode": []string{"disable"}}).Encode(),
}
db, err := gorm.Open(
        "postgres",
        dsn.String(),
)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
```

But the output is:

```
2020/07/07 16:43:44 pq: password authentication failed for user "sample"
```

How do I connect to DB with a user which has no password?

Answer (score 0):

Either assign the user a password and then use it, or change your pg_hba.conf file so that [some other method of authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html) is used for that user/dbname/connection-method/host (and then restart your server so the change takes effect).

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER sample password 'yahkeixuom5R';"
```

Comment: I can connect to db by `postgresql://sample:@/practice` using Python and SQLAlchemy, whereas I haven't change anything in `pg_hba.conf`. So I don't get why can not connect.
Do you have any ideas for connecting by `psql` with a user that has no password?

Comment: @shayanrokrok your app is specifying 'localhost', which uses a 'host' line from pg_hba, while  @/ is using a unix-domain socket, which uses a 'local' line from pg_hba.  They apparently specify different things.

Comment: You are so right. The correct URL is: `postgresql://sample:@localhost/practice`.